# can't retrieve HTML Collection length

Tags: javascript, dynamic

```js
// this sets the inventory figures

function ricercaInCol(tableId,colonna,value){

    const table = document.getElementById('table'); 
    const n_colonne = table.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    document.write(n_colonne);
    const celle = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
    let contatore = 0;
    let occurrMatch = 0;
    for(let j=colonna; j<celle.length; j=(j+n_colonne)){
         if(celle[j].innerText.match(value)){
           occurrMatch++;
           contatore++;
         }
    }
    return occurrMatch;
  };
  ricercaInCol(table,3,'G7');
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: beige;
}
button {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: brown;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}  
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(198, 244, 209);
        color:black;
}
.trAlternate {
    background-color: rgb(108, 117, 202);
        color:black;
}
tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hardware Inventory</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>INVENTORY TEST</h1>
    <h2></h2>
    <table id="table" class="sortable"></table>

<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3run.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/sorttable.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/inventory.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a function that needs to retrieve an HTML Collection length. However when I run:

```
const n_colonne = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
```

the value returned is 0. While when I go with:

```
const n_colonne = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
```

I get the full collection. The script is placed at the  end of body right before the body end tag. The table (generated dynamically by D3.js from a csv file) is placed well before the script. I know that these symptoms are typical of scripts that load before DOM has finished rendering the elements. But this is not the case. I don't understand how this can happen.

```
function ricercaInCol(tableId,colonna,value){
    const table = document.getElementById('tableId'); 
    const n_colonne = table.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    const celle = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
    let contatore = 0;
    let occurrMatch = 0;
    for(let j=colonna; j<celle.length; j=(j+n_colonne)){
         if(celle[j].innerText.match(value)){
           occurrMatch++;
           contatore++;
         }
    }
    return occurrMatch;
  };
```

Comment: It sounds like the elements aren't there when the code runs, but are added later, and you're using `n_colonne` *later*. You've said that it's "not the case" that your script is running before the DOM has finished loading, but that really is the explanation for what you're seeing; the collection [isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: There's a difference between dom content loaded and asynchronous javascript loading content once the dom is loaded. Your d3 code should offer events to hook into to do what you need once table is rendered

Comment: here's a codepen and effectively there it works... the difference is that in codepen I pasted a sample html table statically, while in my case the table generates dynamically... 

https://codepen.io/Lothars/pen/eoEPWB?editors=1111 

thanks @charlietfl I'm not an expert. Any link to a reading on this subject? I'm a bit lost..

Comment: @Lothar - The full content of your question must be **here, on-site**, not offsite in a codepen. Again, [please use Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/), or at the very least, put the full code of the MCVE **in** the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did it.. but the table is generated dynamically in my real scenario, so I don't know how to reproduce that in the snippet. If I add a static html table in the snippet it will throw for sure the correct length.

Comment: @Lothar - I'm afraid that means it's not an MCVE. We can't help you much with code we can't see, but the symptom is quite clear: The elements **are not** in the DOM when you do the query, they get added later.

Comment: thanks @charlietfl for your post, it gave me the hint I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who are like me generating a html table dynamically from a file (csv in this case) and don't know how to handle (yet) situations where dynamically generated elements are not selectable because not available yet when the script runs:

- ensure you state those elements in the html. While the parsing is done, rather than using APPEND to the DOM use instead SELECT (the existing elements) and pass the data to them. In my case I could not select the th tags and inserted them in the html. So the function that generates the table can look like this:

  ```
   var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
  var table = d3.select('#table'); // here select rather than append
    var thead = table.select('thead') // here select rather than append
    var tbody = table.select('tbody') // here select rather than append

    thead.select('tr') // here select rather than append
      .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns)
        .text(function (d) { return d })

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
      .append('tr')

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
                return { column: column, value: row[column] }
          })
      })
      .enter()
    .append('td')
      .text(function (d) { return d.value })

  return table;
  ```

  }

Also... I found out that d3.csv() is asynchronous hence if you use it to extract data and generate a table, restructure your code to take into account the asynchronous nature of the call. This could mean handling all of your logic from inside the d3.csv() call

Answer (score -1):

use `querySelectorAll` instead of getElementByTagName, this will create an array.